# Looping Regression extraction for each regression

Tags: r, loops, regression, extract

I can see this has been almost done before, but i am new to R, and can't figure it out. Pretty much, i have a regression loop (please don't criticise for data-mining) and i need to report some things from each loop into a new list/data-frame/whatever-is-most-appropriate. Here is my code:

```
#Required packages
require(lattice)
require(plyr)


ACDn <- "ACDn.csv"
x <- as.matrix(read.csv(ACDn, colClasses = "numeric"))

#To find which columns are which, in order to split up the overall dataset.
which( colnames(X)=="H95.H30" )
which( colnames(X)=="H99" )

#Here i split all the data into their different types, i.e. LHt = Lidar Heights. Please ignore
#those that are unpopulated, as i am waiting on data to run.

Yall <- x[,c(59:79)]                            #All "True Variables" - BA, MTH, etc.
Y <- Yall[,10]                                  #Specifies which columnn is the Y variable, BA = 10,
                                                #TopHt = 11, SPH = 12, Vol_live = 13, RecovVol = 14

X <- x[,c(1:58,80:95)]                          #All Lidar metrics and combinations.
LHt <- X[,c(28:41,59:74)]
LCv <- X[,c()]
LKu <- X[,c()]
LSk <- X[,c()]
L?? <- X[,c()]

#Create List file. I 

Optmod1 <- 

#Loop Creation, need dataset sizes. The ?? are caused by not knowing the exact sizes 
#of the relative datasets yet. Somewhere in here i would like the an entry for EACH model to be
#appended to a data.frame (or list, whatever is most appropriate), which would state the variables
# i.e. 'y', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', and the Adj. R-squared value (which i guess can be extracted
# through using 'summary(mod)$adj.r.squared). 

For(i in 1:30) {
  For(j in 1:??) {
    For(k in 1:??) {
      For(l in 1:??){
        For(m in 1:??){
          mod <- lm(Y ~ LHt[i] + LCv[j] + LKu[k] + LSk[l] + L??[m])
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So pretty much, after 'mod' has run each time, i just need it to throw 'Y', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', AND the Adjusted.R-Squared (i guess through using "summary(mod)$adj.r.squared") into an extractable table of sorts.

Sorry if any of this is r-illiterate, i am new to this, and have just been given prescribed code before, and as such my basic understanding is sparse.

Thanks for your time!

P.S. Feel free to ask any questions - i'll try really hard to answer them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is

```
Answers = list()
For(i in 1:30) {
  For(j in 1:??) {
    For(k in 1:??) {
      For(l in 1:??){
        For(m in 1:??){
          mod <- lm(Y ~ LHt[i] + LCv[j] + LKu[k] + LSk[l] + L??[m])
          Answers[[length(Answers)+1]] = list(i,j,k,l,m,summary(mod)$adj.r.squared)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which will store the information you want in a list. It works by creating a blank list, which you then append to every time you run your regression model in a loop. However, growing a list like this in a loop is very bad R practice.

You might be better off first writing all the possible formulas of form `LHt[i] + LCv[j] + LKu[k] + LSk[l] + L??[m]` into a list, and then using lapply to do the regression...

First use `expand.grid` to give a data frame with 5 columns, with each column containing one variable name from each category

```
LHT_names = lapply(1:30,function(i) paste("LHt[",i,"]",sep="")) #a list of names of LHT type variables for use in formula
LCv_names = lapply(1:?,function(i) paste("LCv[",i,"]",sep="")) #similar for LCv
LKu_names = ...
LSk_names = ...
L??_names = ...

temp = expand.grid(c(LHt_names, LCv_names, LKu_names, LSk_names, L??_names))
```

Then, use paste and lapply to get a list of formulas:

```
list_of_formulas = lapply(seq_along(nrow(temp)), function(i) paste("Y~",paste(temp[i,],collapse="+"),sep = ""))
```

Then, use lapply to get a list of regression models

```
list_of_models = lapply(list_of_formulas, function(x)  lm(x) )
```

Comment: Thank you so so so much for responding.

My question is: When i do the 2nd thing you say (the better practice) i get an error message:

> LHT_names = lapply(1:30,paste("LHt[",i,"]",sep=""))
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'LHt[1]' of mode 'function' was not found

What do i do?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo... you need to insert `function(i)` before the `paste`. Have a look at `?lapply`, and also have a look at the output of that line when it works.

Comment: Hrmmmm, i got to the end piece of code, and got an error saying that the "=" after `function(x)` is unexpected.

Comment: And if i try to run the first piece of code:

`for(i in 1:30) {
  for(j in 1:17) {
    for(k in 1:2) {
      for(l in 1:2){
      mod <- lm(Y ~ LHt[i] + LCv[j] + LKu[k] + LSk[l])
      Answers[[length(Answers)+1]] = list(i,j,k,l,summary(mod)$adj.r.squared)
      }
    }
  }
}`

i get the following error code: Error in model.frame.default(formula = Y ~ LHt[i] + LCv[j] + LKu[k] +  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'LHt[i]'). I'm not sure what is going on haha, i just started using this program 3 weeks ago, and this learning curve is very steep. (Also, thanks again for helping me).

Comment: check again, that was another typo, I can't write lapply syntax today, apparently.

Comment: for `variable lengths differ`: try to identify which value of i, j , etc the loop is breaking down at (you can do this by putting print(c(i,j,k,l,m)) in the innermost nest of for loops before `mod <- ...`. Then have a look at the lengths of each of these variables.

Comment: haha, it is no problem man, i need all the help i can get here haha. Should i just look at `list_of_models` and that will output what exactly to me? Again, i apologise for my ignorance.

Comment: The output i get from the `print(c(i,j,k,l,m))` is just 1 1 1 1.

Comment: Ah. Yes, you need double square brackets, instead of `LHt[1]`, use `LHt[[1]]`. LHt is a list of lists, so you have to careful with the subset operations. Have a look at `length(LHt[1])` vs `length(LHt[[1]])`

Comment: I can send you my dataset if you'd like?

Comment: I tried restarting R, and clearing the workspace, but that did nothing either. My data (LHt, LCv etc.) are all matrices - does this matter?

Comment: I went back, changed my data from being matrices to data frames, tweak ed the syntax, and it worked. Thanks dude, for being patient.